# Сочетание числительных с существительными

Tags: сочетаемость

1191(одни?) полные сутки - Как правильно?
Всего самолёты находились в воздухе 28 676 часов 
(1191 полных суток). ?

Answer (score 1):

Числительное один, а также составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на один, согласуются с существительными в роде. числе, падеже (один день,  одна задача, одно решение, одни сутки, на одном окне и т.д.). Поэтому правильно: тысяча сто девяносто одни полные сутки.

А где вы видите цифру 2 и в чем проблема с числительным 1?

Comment: Всё правильно у Сержа, но почему-то не видно одобрительных голосов.
Проблемы для существительных pluralia tantum создают только числительные  "два, три, четыре". Мы говорим двое/трое/четверо суток, но  в составные числительные собирательные  включить нельзя ("двадцать двое" суток не получится), и тогда приходится переходить к другим формам. Но для числительного "один" таких проблем нет: двадцать один день, двадцать одни сутки, тысяча сто девяносто одни полные сутки.

Answer (score 0):

Но прибавить один уже не получится. Двое суток – можно, тыща сто девяносто двое суток – нельзя. Надо выкручиваться: девяносто два дня или в течение девяноста двух суток.